# Javascript- how do you convert this foreach loop to a regular for-loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

This nested  loop is running really slow in my app so I'm trying to change it to use regular for-loops instead of foreach.  I'm a little confused on the find() part.  Can someone help me convert this nested loop so that it doesn't use any foreach loops?  thanks.

```
   var filters = [];
    if (selectionTagFilters.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectionTagFilters.length; i++) {
            filterTree.forEach(function find(tag) {
                if (tag.tagCategoryId == selectionTagFilters[i].tag.tagCategoryId) {
                    tag.tags.forEach(function find(tag) {
                        if (tag.tagId == selectionTagFilters[i].tag.tagId) {
                            filters.push({ tagHeader: tag.tagHeader, tagId: tag.tagId, tagCategoryId: tag.tagCategoryId });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the fact that the loops are `forEach` is what's slowing this down.

Comment: Changing to `for` won't make it faster to be honnest.... and the fact the the function is named find doesn't affect anything.

Comment: A lot of websites say foreach loops run slower.  Here's an example: http://jsperf.com/fast-array-foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
var filters = [],
    selectionTagFilterItem = null,
    filterTreeItem = null,
    tagItem = null;
for(var i = 0, ii = selectionTagFilters.length; i < ii; i++) {
    selectionTagFilterItem = selectionTagFilters[i];
    for(var fti, ftii = filterTree.length; fti < ftii; fti++) {
        filterTreeItem = filterTree[fti];
        if (filterTreeItem.tagCategoryId != selectionTagFilterItem.tag.tagCategoryId) continue;
        for(var ti = 0, tii = filterTreeItem.tags.length; ti < tii; ti++) {
            tagItem = filterTreeItem.tags[ti];
            if (tagItem.tagId != selectionTagFilterItem.tag.tagId) continue;
            filters.push({ tagHeader: tagItem.tagHeader, tagId: tagItem.tagId, tagCategoryId: tagItem.tagCategoryId });
        }
    }
}
```